# Looking for help debugging a clicking game using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a game where a random number is chosen and four buttons are given (they will eventually be crystals).

I'm trying to make it that each button has a set, hidden value, and the goal is the match the random number given exactly.

I thought the following would give that to me, but I'm wrong. The player seems to win the second the program runs, and wins and losses are not written into the html as I had expected from my if statements.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  var crystalNumber1;
  var crystalNumber2;
  var crystalNumber3;
  var crystalNumber4;
  var total = 0;
  var currentTotal = $("#total");


  function makeCrystal1() {
    crystalNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1
  };

  function makeCrystal2() {
    crystalNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1
  };

  function makeCrystal3() {
    crystalNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1
  };

  function makeCrystal4() {
    crystalNumber4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1
  };


  function makeRandom() {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  }

  function reset() {
    makeRandom();
    makeCrystal1();
    makeCrystal2();
    makeCrystal3();
    makeCrystal4();
    total = 0;
  }

  reset();

  var win = 0;
  var losses = 0;

  $("#random-number").append(randomNumber);


  function addTo(number) {
    total = total + number;
  }


  $("#crystal1").on("click", function() {
    addTo(crystalNumber1);
    currentTotal.html(total);
  });

  $("#crystal2").on("click", function() {
    addTo(crystalNumber2);
    currentTotal.html(total);
  });

  $("#crystal3").on("click", function() {
    addTo(crystalNumber3);
    currentTotal.html(total);
  });

  $("#crystal4").on("click", function() {
    addTo(crystalNumber4);
    currentTotal.html(total);
  });



  if (total > randomNumber) {
    losses++;
    reset();
    $("#messages").html("Oh no! You destroyed your crystals!");
  }

  if (total = randomNumber) {
    wins++;
    $("#wins").html(wins);
    reset();
    $("#messages").html("You are a crystal master!");
  }


})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Crystal Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Crystal Game <small>Can you match the number?</small></h1>
    </div>

    <p>A random number will appear.</p>
    <p>Click on the crystals to find out their individual value.</p>
    <p>Win the game by clicking the right combination of crystals to match the number. Don't go over the number or you lose!</p>
    <p>Good luck!</p>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div id="random-number"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p id="alert"></p>
        <p>Wins:
          <div id="wins"></div>
        </p>
        <p>Losses:
          <div id="losses"></div>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a id="crystal1" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">
          <img src="" alt="">crystal1
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a id="crystal2" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">
          <img src="" alt="">crystal2
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a id="crystal3" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">
          <img src="" alt="">crystal3
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a id="crystal4" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">
          <img src="" alt="">crystal4
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      The current total is:
      <div id="total"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="crystal-count"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="messages"></div>
    </div>



  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: incorrect comparison operator in `if (total = randomNumber) ` ... should be `===`. You are assigning total not comparing

Comment: Like @charlietfl wrote, the user wins immediately because `if (total = randomNumber)` is always truthy. You also only need one function to randomly generate the crystal numbers. Creating a unique function for each crystal but having all of them perform the same task is redundant.

Comment: @charlietfl yes! duh!

Comment: @Nadav yes. I realized this after I created a majority of the program. I totally agree. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 1):

Problems:

1. Your `if()` conditionals only run on page load. Wrap them in a function that can be called inside `addTo()` so you are checking every time total changes. I wrapped them in `function checkStatus`
2. Missing any html insert for `$('#losses')` when you blow past the number
3. Invalid conditional comparison operator in `if (total = randomNumber)`

Got it mostly working below but don't intend to rewrite the whole app or enhance features. Some of the repetitive code could easily be consolidated... like using one click handler for all buttons and check id to see which number to add

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  var crystalNumber1;
  var crystalNumber2;
  var crystalNumber3;
  var crystalNumber4;
  var total = 0;
  var currentTotal = $("#total");


  function makeCrystal1() {
    crystalNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1
  };

  function makeCrystal2() {
    crystalNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1
  };

  function makeCrystal3() {
    crystalNumber3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1
  };

  function makeCrystal4() {
    crystalNumber4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1
  };


  function makeRandom() {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  }

  function reset() {
    makeRandom();
    makeCrystal1();
    makeCrystal2();
    makeCrystal3();
    makeCrystal4();
    total = 0;
  }

  reset();

  var win = 0;
  var losses = 0;

  $("#random-number").append(randomNumber);


  function addTo(number) {
    total = total + number;
    checkStatus();// added new
  }


  $("#crystal1").on("click", function() {
    addTo(crystalNumber1);
    currentTotal.html(total);
    
  });

  $("#crystal2").on("click", function() {
    addTo(crystalNumber2);
    currentTotal.html(total);
    
  });

  $("#crystal3").on("click", function() {
    addTo(crystalNumber3);
    currentTotal.html(total);   
  });

  $("#crystal4").on("click", function() {
    addTo(crystalNumber4);
    currentTotal.html(total);
    
  });


function checkStatus(){// added new
  if (total > randomNumber) {
    losses++;
    reset();
    $('#losses').html(losses);// added new
    $("#messages").html("Oh no! You destroyed your crystals!");
  }

  if (total === randomNumber) {
    wins++;
    $("#wins").html(wins);
    reset();
    $("#messages").html("You are a crystal master!");
  }
}

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Crystal Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Crystal Game <small>Can you match the number?</small></h1>
    </div>

    <p>A random number will appear.</p>
    <p>Click on the crystals to find out their individual value.</p>
    <p>Win the game by clicking the right combination of crystals to match the number. Don't go over the number or you lose!</p>
    <p>Good luck!</p>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div id="random-number"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p id="alert"></p>
        <p>Wins:
          <div id="wins"></div>
        </p>
        <p>Losses:
          <div id="losses"></div>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a id="crystal1" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">
          <img src="" alt="">crystal1
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a id="crystal2" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">
          <img src="" alt="">crystal2
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a id="crystal3" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">
          <img src="" alt="">crystal3
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <a id="crystal4" class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">
          <img src="" alt="">crystal4
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="row">
      The current total is:
      <div id="total"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="crystal-count"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="messages"></div>
    </div>



  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I get the logic now. The program is basically only checking these if statements when the page loads, and then never again because it's not associated with any other function or event.